# Firebase .httpsCallable functions always returning "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nativescript

I'm not sure I'm 100% on await and promise chaining, but I cannot for the life of me understand why any time I try to pass data to a httpsCallable function I get a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error without the function ever being called.

I'm just trying to pass the user object returned from **signInWithEmailAndPassword** to my **httpsCallable** but cannot figure out how to without said error. Any pointers appreciated <3

```js
const importFirebase = () => import(process.env.VUE_APP_MODE === 'web' ? 
    'firebase' : 'nativescript-plugin-firebase/app')
```

```js
const firebase = await importFirebase()
firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(signInData.email, signInData.password)
        .then((user) => { 
               return firebase.functions().httpsCallable('doSomething')(user)
        })
```

Comment: Promise chaining isn't your problem here, but you typically don't mix async/await along with then/catch.  You pick one or the other and stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error typically means you're trying to serialize an object with internal circular references.  The first thing you should try is any object other than `user`.  Then, try composing an object based on what you pull out of `user`.  Just don't pass `user` itself, since it might not be safe to serialize in the default manner.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. When I stopped sending the entire ```user``` it became easier to work with. I believe the issue may have been coming from the ```.httpsCallable('doSomething')(user)``` bit—I stopped having this issue after creating ```const doSomething = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('doSomething')``` and then calling ```return doSomething({user})``` where ```user``` is the specific data I need for the function.